# Adjusting Docker Run command to gItlab-ci.yaml for OWASP ZAP image

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, zap, zapproxy

Trying to run OWASP ZAP Docker Build in the headless mode described [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Docker#user-content-zap-headless):

```
docker run -u zap -p 8080:8080 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080
```

But can't figure out how to adapt that to a gitlab-ci.yaml. On gitlab 9.4 and think a [service command](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#setting-a-command-for-the-service) should do it, but haven't got it to work.
Tried:

```
security_test:
  image: python:2.7
  stage: test
  services:
  - name: owasp/zap2docker-stable
    alias: zap
    command: ["docker run -u zap -p 8080:8080 -i owasp_zap zap.sh -port 8080 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.key=$ZAP_API_KEY -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config scanner.strength=INSANE"]
  script:
    - export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/backend/lib:$PYTHONPATH
    - pip install -r qa/security/requirements.txt
    - BASE_URL="https://example.com" ZAP="http://owasp__zap2docker-stable:8080" ZAP_API_KEY=$ZAP_API_KEY python qa/security/zap_scanner.py
```

This gets this error:

```
 ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"docker run -u zap -p 8080:8080 -i owasp_zap zap.sh -port 8080 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.key=$ZAP_API_KEY -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config scanner.strength=INSANE\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"
 ...
```

Also ran docker inspect on it running locally and it shows the past as

```
"env": [
    ...
    "ZAP_PATH=/zap/zap.sh",
    ...
```

So I changed command to

```
    command: ["zap.sh -port 8080 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.key=$ZAP_API_KEY -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config scanner.strength=INSANE"]
```

But still get the error:

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"/zap/zap zap.sh -port 8080 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.key=$ZAP_API_KEY -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config scanner.strength=INSANE\\\": stat /zap/zap zap.sh -port 8080 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.key=$ZAP_API_KEY -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config scanner.strength=INSANE: no such file or directory\"\n"
...
```

This seems to be the [install file](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/3b805ff27d681dd3b4051ffb61b54b7ae26d1700/build/docker/Dockerfile-live). I'm trying to use custom setting and an api key so not looking for answers like just use default settings or zap baseline.

Answer (score 0):

Change the command

```
command: ["zap.sh -port 8080 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.key=$ZAP_API_KEY -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config scanner.strength=INSANE"]
```

to

```
command: zap.sh -port 8080 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.key=$ZAP_API_KEY -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true -config scanner.strength=INSANE
```

Having a array means that each command parameter needs to be separate elements of array and not like you mentioned everything in first element of the array

Comment: If I do that it doesn't build due to a "yaml invalid" error. The linter at ci/lint says: "Status: syntax is incorrect 
Error: service command should be an array of strings"

Comment: To be clear, the issue is in Gitlab, not docker. Locally docker-compose works launching with a command like that.

Comment: OK. Will look into the issue again tonight